# Python and PostGres | Showing data in a QLabel (psycopg2)

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

im using Postgres together with python(psycopg2). Im trying to insert data in a QLabel. It shows the data, but the data comes with clinges. How do I get rid of the clinges?

My code:

```
    def getstunden():
        conn = None
        try:
            conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres password=test")
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT stunden FROM ueberstunden WHERE name = 'test'")
            row = cur.fetchone()

            while row is not None:
                self.s_test.setText(str(row))
                row = cur.fetchone()
            cur.close()
        except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
            print(error)
        finally:
            if conn is not None:
                conn.close()
```

This is what I get out of it:

[I want it to just show 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApgDi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per here [Cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html):

> Note

> cursor objects are iterable, so, instead of calling explicitly fetchone() in a loop, the object itself can be used:

> cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test;")
> for record in cur:
> print record

> (1, 100, "abc'def")

> (2, None, 'dada')

> (3, 42, 'bar')

So to simplify:

```
 def getstunden():
        conn = None
        try:
            conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres password=test")
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT stunden FROM ueberstunden WHERE name = 'test'")
            for row in cur:
                self.s_test.setText(str(row[0]))
            cur.close()
        except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
            print(error)
        finally:
            if conn is not None:
                conn.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

It's just like this

```
print(row[0])
```

in your code

```
def getstunden():
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres password=test")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT stunden FROM ueberstunden WHERE name = 'test'")
        row = cur.fetchone()

        while row is not None:
            #row without the brackets                            
            self.s_test.setText(str(row[0]))
            row = cur.fetchone()            
        cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
```

Comment: Was easier than I expected! Thank you.